# Control volume example

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

Do lungs of human body can be an example of control volume?
I think it's not as for a control volume the mass can flow and energy too through system but i mean volume should be fixed .WHereas the volume of our lungs changes so it should not be control volume system.

Comment: Nothing needs to be fixed about a control volume, except that it has to have walls around a volume. The reason you define one is so you can write expressions for what's in it and what crosses the walls, so you know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fundamental reason why a control volume must comprise a fixed region of space.  It is also possible to have a moving/deforming control volume, but this must be taken into account in writing the energy balance equations for the control volume.  Certainly, it is much easier to work with a fixed control volume.